# Create Mat-table with unknown number of mid columns

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to create a mat-table with the first column is the name of the objective of the product then a number of column has the column name is the name of the product and then a column with header is a + button to add the product

However the table header sometimes right, sometimes wrong. The + column sometimes go to the middle of the product columns.

Is there a way to make the mat-table fit my desciption? If there is, please show me the flow. 
The images bellow is the design I tried: The first table has no value and has 1 column. The second table has two column in the middle and wrong with + column

[image]

Comment: Could you include an image of the desired layout of the table?

Comment: Okay, I have uploaded the image

Comment: The first table has mistake when show the data so just focus on the header column

Comment: So you need a Material table with dynamic columns? Check this other question which seems to be related: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266723/how-to-get-labels-as-name-propery-from-the-backend-with-angular-material/59274431#59274431)

Comment: Do you need dynamic table? If yes, can you provided the json or object from which is should be generated?

Comment: Yes, however I have just figured it out how to fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the column in the above pictures will appear if there too many request to my api that is pending. Therefore I need to reduce the number of request to API into 1 and it will be alright. Hope this will help anybody have problem like me.